# C++ only compiles only after restarting Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, windows, mingw, eclipse-cdt

When I make a new C++ project, the compilation gives an error "Launch failed. Binary not found." This is after I build. But I don't think exe is created.

But the problem does away when I close Eclipse and start again. I build again, then it compiles without any error.

Window 7

MinGW installed

Comment: What OS is this on? On mac you must select the MacOSX GCC toolchain in order to produce an executable.

Comment: I installed mingw64 on win10 which gave me the GCC compiler. I don't recall the details since I mainly use os x.

Comment: I already installed Mingw